# Would whitening correlated inputs improve kernel estimates in a Volterra expansion?

Tags: multicollinearity, convolution

I’m modelling a discrete-time 1-dimensional signal $y(t)$ as a sum of two input variables $x_1(t), x_2(t)$ convolved with their respective kernels plus noise

$y=x_1*g_1+x_2*g_2+\eta$

and I’m estimating the kernels $g_1$, $g_2$ by minimizing squared error with ridge regularization.

Both input variables are positive-valued, not Gaussian or "nice" in any way, and correlated. Besides the good fit to the data, I care a lot about the correctly found kernels -- so as far as I understand, multicollinearity is an issue here.

Selecting subsets of data where the correlation between $x_1$ and $x_2$ is low, works somewhat. But I wonder if there is a more rigorous solution.

For example, would whitening the input variables and fitting the model on the whole dataset give a better kernel estimates?

And how would then the kernels of the whitened inputs relate to the kernels before whitening?

E.g. if the model with uncorrelated inputs $x_1'(t)$ and $x_2'(t)$ is $y=x_1'*g_1'+x_2'*g_2'+\eta$ where $x(t)'=Wx(t)=\begin{bmatrix} x_1'(t) \\ x_2'(t) \end{bmatrix}$ with $x(t)=\begin{bmatrix} x_1(t) \\ x_2(t) \\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $W$ its whitening matrix, is it possible to express $g_1'$ and $g_2'$ in terms of $g_1$, $g_2$, and $W$?